# Docusign: Is there an API from DocuSign which tells me if the user in an account has Electronic Seal permission or not

Tags: docusignapi

The requirement is not to send the document for seal signature, if the user does not have permission for electronic seal.
If the user does not have the permission Docusign throws an error "Invalid_Seal_Name". 
But we want to proactively prevent user from sending a document for Seal Signature.
We are using Docusign API version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest technique, I believe, is to do what you're doing: attempt to send the envelope, including the `seal` recipient. If it works, the user has the ability to use the feature.